# What's the maximum length should I allow to avoid Catastrophic backtracking?

Tags: javascript, regex

The line is approximately 7915621 in length and is actually the view state value of an ASPX website.

I get the original HTML of the site, then pass it line by line to the extract function, and as soon as it reaches the view_state line containing that long string, the regex become stuck.

Here is the regex pattern that get stuck,

```
/[\w\.]+\@[\w]+(?:\.[\w]{3}|\.[\w]{2}\.[\w]{2})\b/gi
```

I thought about setting a maximum line length to skip this line or any other lines like that but I can't think of a optimal size as I care about false positives.

Comment: You're parsing an HTML page using regex?

Comment: @Amy No. I parse a pattern on a HTML page using Regex.

Comment: You parse a *pattern* on an HTML page?  What does that mean?

Comment: @Pointy: no, `[\w\.]+` is totally different from `.+`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte how? "Any word character or ...." oh

Comment: @jeffbRTC I know what *extraction* is.  I'm trying to better understand *what you are trying to parse*.  No need to be smart about it.

Comment: @Pointy: the dot in a character class is seen as a dot and nothing else. You can rewrite it like that: `(?:\w|\.)+`

Comment: yes I get that, sorry

Comment: @Amy The pattern is for extracting emails

Comment: So you're trying to extract email addresses from an HTML document by running the regex line by line on the HTML.  okay.

Comment: @Amy Yes and I get haunted by big line on the way :)

Comment: If I may propose a (possibly) more efficient solution, search the HTML document for the indexes of each `@` character, which is in every email address.  From each index, get a substring 20 characters to each side, plenty long to hold an email address.  Then run the regex.  The `indexOf` operations should be really fast, and the 40-character substrings should also be fast to search.  This would automatically limit the amount of backtracking possible.  I think.  Just an idea.

Comment: @Amy it would probably be fine to go for 500 characters on either side of the `@`, it'll still be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\w\.]+` is found so many times in your document that it becomes a problem to process them with your expression.

Reducing the amount of places to start searching at is a possible solution. E.g. using a word boundary.

`(?:\.\w{3}|\.\w{2}\.\w{2})` can be streamlined as `\.\w{2}(?:\w|\.\w{2})`.

Use

```js
/\b[\w.]+@\w+\.\w{2}(?:\w|\.\w{2})\b/gi
```

Or, get rid of the brackets

```js
/\b\w+(?:\.\w+)*@\w+\.\w{2}(?:\w|\.\w{2})\b/gi
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w{2}                    word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (2
                           times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w{2}                    word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (2
                             times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```